# Is there a way to skip certain stages based on a pre-merge request and post-merge request (Jenkins/gitlab)

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to build a CI with Gitlab+Jenkins. what I did so far is this :

I already set the web-hook between Jenkins and GitLab to trigger merge requests and push events.

I just need one last thing that i can't seem to figure out:

Once the merge request is created(before it is accepted and mereged) and the web-hook is triggered i need some stages to be skipped.

Once the request is accepted and merged and a new build is made, i need some other stages to be skipped.

thanks

Comment: If you post the relevant sections of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, we may be able to give you better guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The following documentation links should prove helpful.

[`.gitlab-ci.yml` only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)

[`.gitlab-ci.yml` rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)